# Resetear formulario ajax append

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Buenas, estoy con pequeño problemita.. Cuando abro el campo para editar.. Me carga la imagen actual, y abajo el input file.. Cuando lo cambio y doy submit, funciona todo perfecto.. Mi problema es.. Que cuando intento editar otro campo, se abre el modal, pero continua la imagen anterior, la actual, y tambien en el input file el archivo que se habia subido.. Alguien puede ayudarme? Dejo aquí mi codigo..

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Portada de Inicio actual</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div id="f3223f235" ></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Portada de Inicio nueva</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="file" id="file-editanoti"  name="portada" class="form-control" accept="images/jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="prev_edinoti" style="margin:auto; display: flex; margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
```

el div PREV_EDINOTI es el ID donde se muestra la imagen nueva que se va cargar.
JS para cargar los archivos y donde muestro mi imagen

```
function editarNoti(idNoticia){
    $('#form_edi_noti')[0].reset();
    var url = 'php/notiEditar.php';
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:'id='+idNoticia, // envia a PHP ej.: $_POST['id'];
        success: function(valores){
                var datos = eval(valores);
                $('#edi_noti').val('Edicion');
                $('#idnoticiia').val(idNoticia);
                $('#titnoticia').val(datos[0]);
                $('#fechanoticia').val(datos[1]);
                $('#fecha_noti2').val(datos[2]);
                $('#direnoti').val(datos[3]);
                $('#direnoti2').val(datos[4]);
                $('#f3223f235').append("<img src=../imagenes/noticias/"+datos[3]+"/"+datos[5]+" style='max-width: 50%'>" ); //portadagaleria
                $('#f3223f23534').val(datos[5]);
                $('#portadagaleria').val(datos[6]);
                $('#anexo').val(datos[7]);
                $('#galeria').val(datos[8]);
                $('#intCatnoticia').val(datos[9]);
                $('#edita-noti').modal({
                    show:true,
                    backdrop:'static'
                });
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

onsubmit llama a esta funcion

```
function editaNoti(){
    var archivos = new FormData($("#form_edi_noti")[0]);
    var url = 'php/notiEdita.php';
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data: archivos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(edicion){
            if ($('#edi_noti').val() == 'Edicion'){
            alertify.success("Edición realizada.");
            $('#edita-noti').modal('hide');
            $('#noti').html(edicion);
            return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ya probastes limpiar todo el formulario antes ó después de haber enviado el formulario

Comment: Si, está justo aquí..
 {function editarNoti(idNoticia){
    $('#form_edi_noti')[0].reset();}

Answer (score 1):

Para saber:

Ya solucioné lo de que se deje de acumular las imágenes al abrir el modal.. Tenia que cambiar el append por html.. Ahora solo me queda limpiar el input del file luego de hacer submit

Answer (score 0):

Por lo visto, te hace falta regresar el formulario a su estado inicial:

Usando `jQuery`:

```
  $("#idDeTuFormulario")[0].reset();
```

Usando `JavaScript` puro y crudo:

```
document.getElementById("idDeTuFormulario").reset();
```

Comment: Fijate que al realizar la llamada a editarNoticia ya está la funcion que me dices, y lo hace, pero lo que no hace es limpiar el input del file

Comment: vale, no me fijé, en ese caso dale con el javascript: window.fileInputForm.reset();

Comment: Ok, pero en que linea lo inserto?